# Preview ASP files without server

Tags: asp.net, browser, asp-classic

How can I get any browser to just treat a .asp/.aspx file as if it was .html and render it? (Without installing ASP server). It always pops up with a download box or displays the source.

Preferably for IE8. On Vista.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what outcome you are looking for?  You need the server to interpret the server side logic.

Comment: You could rename it to .html potentially

Comment: You're right. But I only care about the HTML. Ignoring the ASP logic is fine. This is what IE 7 did and I'm using it to preview work in editplus.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Visual Web Developer 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/)?  It's a no-cost way to develop and view ASP.NET pages.

Comment: The default configuration of the preview-server in my Web Developer 2008 Express won't execute "classic ASP" files when i choose "View in Browser". It shows the error page " This type of page is not served. The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden. The extension '.asp' may be incorrect..." So can one somehow persuade it to execute classic .asp files?

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do this in Firefox (i.e., with the awesome [force content-type](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Internet-Applications-Addons/Mozilla-Extensions/Force-Content-Type.shtml) firefox extension!), but I don't know how to do it in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You can just "render .asp" files in a browser like an HTML file. Browsers don't "speak" ASP.

ASP files contain scripts which are executed on a server so you have to have the server installed to get back the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

I realise you wanted server-less, but in light of forcing a browser to render and ignore server side tags, as an alternative you could use [Cassini web server](http://ultidev.com/products/Cassini/) - it's very lightweight and portable and you can still edit the asp/aspx files directly and it will render fine in a browser..

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Robert Cartaino on this: you won't see what you expect to.  But since these are your files, you could just temporarily re-name them to *.html and see what you get.